# How to get the date fomat displayed in input of type date using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, input

I have an input type=date that displays in format MM/DD/YYYY, i'm working on a copy/paste functionnality that allows me to paste a certain date in the input.

The problem is that the input only accepts text in format YYYY-MM-DD, which is not the displayed format, i don't want to force the user to use a specific format while copying dates.

I'm looking for a way to get the format used to display the date (the browser format) so that I can convert the copied text to a date of format YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLocaleString`. The Swedish option is used to parse the date to  YYYY-MM-DD

```js
const dateSlashed = '03/30/2023';
const parsedDate = new Date(dateSlashed);
const dateDashed = parsedDate.toLocaleString('se-SE', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }); 

console.log(dateDashed);
```

Comment: i don't think you understood the question, why you assumed that the dateDisplay should have the format MM/DD/YYYY?

Comment: I just added a sample method for conversion. `dateDisplay` was  just a name without assuming anything else. I changed it to be less confusing.  PS  maybe add some your code to the question then ;)

Comment: What if the variable dateSlashed had a date such as '30/03/2023', the instantiation of a new Date(...) will return an invalid date result

Comment: In that case write a helper function that supports many date formats or maybe use a library such as moment.js